# The method fromDatagramSocket(DatagramSocket) is undefined for the type ParcelFileDescriptor

Tags: android, eclipse, udp, audio-streaming, datagram

I am trying to pipeline some audio over a udp socket on android using eclipse

I keep getting the following error

"The method fromDatagramSocket(DatagramSocket) is undefined for the type ParcelFileDescriptor"

The android docs show that such a method is already available and I believe this is the proper way to create a UDP pipeline

Reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#fromDatagramSocket(java.net.DatagramSocket)

Code :

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port, InetAddress.getByName(hostnameUDP));
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromDatagramSocket(socket);
```

Comment: were you able to stream audio? I am working on streaming video and not getting a good source to start with.

Comment: Yes, it worked well but I had a problem creating the right buffer to store / play the live stream which caused a small delay. Where are you stuck at, did you try using the protocols used to stream live video ?

Comment: I need to broadcast the streaming and broadcasting is possible through UDP only as TCP is point to point. I am still looking at the documenations and did not find a good place to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the included Android Library which was Android 2.2
Changed it to Android 4.3 and it worked
Apparently the older version of the Android library did not have UDP defined